# I need to make these collapsible buttons highlanders

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 collapsible buttons, but you can keep them open all at the same time, I've been looking for a way to make them mutually-exclusive, so when you open one if there's another one open it closes.

This is the code I used for the buttons, I need to know how to keep only one open at a time time

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.informacion {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 190px;
  display: flex;
}

/*button:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0631/2886/2962/files/01.jpg?v=1690838660");
  color: #fff;
}

button:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0631/2886/2962/files/02.jpg?v=1690838660");
  color: #fff;
}*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .informacion {
    margin-left: -70px;
  }

}

.collapsible {
  background-color: rgba(250, 206, 205, 0.6);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*padding: 18px;*/
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; /*en odern; top, right, bottom, left*/
  width: 800px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  border: solid #facecd 5px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.collapsible {
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: -60px;
  font-family: 'Axiforma';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

/*.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}*/

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  right: 70px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #fde2e2;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.content p {
  /*margin-left: 100px;*/
  font-family: 'Axiforma';
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.content li {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="informacion">
  <button class="collapsible">ABOUT US</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Maria Cecilia Sparacio, the founder of The Pink Room Shapewear (Family business), hails from Cali, Colombia. After studying law and working as a bank manager in Bogota, Colombia, Maria arrived in the United States in 2001. Initially planning for a temporary stay to improve her English skills on a student visa, she was captivated by the opportunities this country had to offer, leading her to pursue the American dream.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="collapsible">F.A.Q</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>We have compiled a comprehensive list of questions and answers to provide you with the information you need about our shape-wear products and services.
      Whether you're curious about the types of shape-wear we offer, how to choose the right size, or our return policy, you'll find the answers <a href="https://inthepinkroom.com/pages/frequently-asked-questions">here.</a></p>
  </div>

  <button class="collapsible">LOCATIONS</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>You can find us at
      <ul>
        <li>249 Morris Avenue, Elizabeth New Jersey 07208, United States</li>
        <li>1994 Morris Avenue, Union New Jersey 07083, United States</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's a highlander?

Comment: While "*making it Highlander,"* is now my favourite phrase to explain the concept of "*mutually-exclusive*," I've edited the question to use an existing, understood explanatory phrase for what you meant to convey.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i wasn't sure how it was called, and i used once a wordpress plugin that did that and thats how it was call in that plugin

Answer (score 0):

There is a canonical way to only have one button area open at a time. To start, give all the buttons in the group the same class. Then, you add the following eventListener to all of them

```
var action = (e) => {
  document.querySelector(".btnGroup ~ DIV").forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  });
  e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block")
}

document.querySelector(".btnGroup").forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener("click", action);
```

```js
var action = (e) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".btnGroup ~ DIV").forEach( (elem) => {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  });
//  e.target.querySelector("~DIV").style.display = "block";
  var elem = e.target;
  while (elem.tagName != "DIV") {
    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  }
  elem.style.display = "block";
}

document.querySelectorAll(".btnGroup").forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener("click", action)
);
```

```html
<button class="btnGroup">A</button>
<div>abc</div>
<button class="btnGroup">B</button>
<div>def</div>
<button class="btnGroup">C</button>
<div>ghi</div>
```